# ggplot2 confusion matrix conditional fill

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-caret, confusion-matrix

I would like the confusion matrix to have two different scales. For true positives/negatives, I would like green for high and red for low. For false results, I would like the colors inverted. This may require two legends? Which may be cumbersome for interpretation, but I feel the inverted colors are more intuitive. Your true results should be high (green for good), and your negative results should be low (green for good in this case).

If there are other suggestions or best practices to this other than what I am suggesting, I am open to other options.

```r
library(caret)
library(tidyverse)
data("GermanCredit")
cm <- confusionMatrix(GermanCredit$Class, sample(GermanCredit$Class))

cm$table %>%
  data.frame() %>% 
  mutate(Prediction = factor(Prediction, levels = c("Good", "Bad"))) %>%
  group_by(Reference) %>% 
  mutate(total = sum(Freq)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Reference, Prediction, fill = Freq)) +
  geom_tile() +
  geom_text(aes(label = Freq), size = 8) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "#ea4434", high = "#badb33") +
  scale_x_discrete(position = "top") +
  geom_tile(color = "black", fill = "black", alpha = 0)
```

[image]

I've added to my question based on some comments: I would like for the irrelevant diagonals to be white and the red(low) and green(high) scale to apply only to the true positive/negative results. For example, the plot below partially achieves this, except I have set the low to white...I would like the low to be red while the white squares to remain white.

```r
library(reprex)
library(caret)
#> Loading required package: lattice
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
library(tidyverse)
data("GermanCredit")
cm <- confusionMatrix(GermanCredit$Class, sample(GermanCredit$Class))

cm$table %>%
  data.frame() %>% 
  mutate(Prediction = factor(Prediction, levels = c("Good", "Bad"))) %>%
  group_by(Reference) %>% 
  mutate(
    total = sum(Freq),
    frac_fill = if_else(Prediction == Reference, Freq / total, 0),
    frac = Freq / total * frac_fill
  ) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Prediction, Reference, fill = frac_fill)) +
  geom_tile() +
  geom_text(aes(label = str_c(Freq, ", ", round(frac * 100), "%")), size = 8) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "#badb33") +
  scale_x_discrete(position = "top") +
  geom_tile(color = "black", fill = "black", alpha = 0)
```

[image]

Comment: You could probably make negative values to invert the direction of an outcome being good or bad. Please post a sample of data that makes this problem reproducible

Comment: @camille OP is using built-in data.

Comment: @Gregor Got it, wasn't familiar with caret's datasets. To clarify, we want green when reference == prediction?

Comment: Not an answer, but usually I see confusion matrices with just a single scale, like you have it. In general the only correct predictions are on the main diagonal so on any usual matrix like [this example](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjbrvL-4ZLcAhVhqFQKHUZYDFgQjRx6BAgBEAU&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mathworks.com%2Fmatlabcentral%2Fanswers%2F283949-string-class-for-confusion-matrix&psig=AOvVaw2wl4_ufbvhZDKgEmBIfVPN&ust=1531251360678089) you are less looking for a particular colour and rather just any mass off the diagonal.

Comment: I would therefore just choose a scale that sets white to be `low`, which I think clearly communicates where there is confusion. Here I just changed `low` to `ffffff` and [I think it is clearer](https://i.imgur.com/Og48emU.png) (and doesn't need two legends)

Comment: @CalumYou This is a similar suggestion to me wanting two scales. In your suggestion, we only want colors on the true positive/negative diagonals, since we are only concerned with reference == prediction. In both cases, you kind of need two scales, or the scales to only be applied to the latter. So it still seems like we need a conditional fill here. I'm not sure the easiest way to accomplish this.

Comment: @CalumYou Your white example works partially, but the colors on the irrelevant diagonals (the false values, i.e reference != prediction), makes the colors kind of noisy.

Comment: I think the point is that when you look at a confusion matrix, you only care whether or not the values are on the diagonal or not; you use the grid to see what is being mispredicted rather than the colour. If you imagine your proposed colour scheme, a perfect classification would be a completely green grid, rather than in this one-colour scheme where a perfect classification is a green diagonal.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want a diverging scale, which requires making one of the scale negative and one positive. I made a variable `frac_directed` that just is the negative of `frac_fill` if the prediction is "Bad", although this might be the opposite of what you're looking for. Then using `scale_fill_gradient2` instead of `scale_fill_gradient`, you can set a midpoint (defaults 0, which is appropriate here) and a middle fill value.

```r
library(caret)
library(tidyverse)
data("GermanCredit")
cm <- confusionMatrix(GermanCredit$Class, sample(GermanCredit$Class))

cm$table %>%
  data.frame() %>% 
  mutate(Prediction = factor(Prediction, levels = c("Good", "Bad"))) %>%
  group_by(Reference) %>% 
  mutate(
    total = sum(Freq),
    frac_fill = if_else(Prediction == Reference, Freq / total, 0),
    frac = Freq / total * frac_fill
  ) %>%
  mutate(frac_directed = if_else(Prediction == "Bad", frac_fill * -1, frac_fill)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Prediction, Reference, fill = frac_directed)) +
  geom_tile(color = "black") +
  geom_text(aes(label = str_c(Freq, ", ", round(frac * 100), "%")), size = 8) +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "red", mid = "white", high = "#badb33") +
  scale_x_discrete(position = "top")
```

[image]

Created on 2018-07-09 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Thanks. This looks good. The only change I would make is for the percentages not to reflect zero for the white squares. it looks counter-intuitive.

Comment: How do you want to go about that? The calculations all come from the code in the question

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's an attempt that basically uses inverted fill values for the off-diagonal tiles. I inverted the axes to be how I think confusion matrices are usually portrayed. I guess what this shows is that the model is better at predicting `Good` than `Bad`, but I think it obscures what is actually being confused when it is confused. The legend is also not the most informative when presented like this, I might even just leave it off.

```r
library(caret)
#> Loading required package: lattice
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
library(tidyverse)
data("GermanCredit")
cm <- confusionMatrix(GermanCredit$Class, sample(GermanCredit$Class))

cm$table %>%
  data.frame() %>% 
  mutate(Prediction = factor(Prediction, levels = c("Good", "Bad"))) %>%
  group_by(Reference) %>% 
  mutate(
    total = sum(Freq),
    frac = Freq / total,
    frac_fill = if_else(Prediction == Reference, Freq / total, 1 - (Freq / total))
    ) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Prediction, Reference, fill = frac_fill)) +
  geom_tile() +
  geom_text(aes(label = str_c(Freq, ", ", round(frac * 100), "%")), size = 8) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "#ea4434", high = "#badb33") +
  scale_x_discrete(position = "top") +
  geom_tile(color = "black", fill = "black", alpha = 0)
```

[image]

Created on 2018-07-09 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Thanks! I see how this looks confusing. I modified my question. See above. Maybe it can get us closer to the diagonal solution you posted in the comments with white for the squares that are irrelevant and a color scale for the true positives/negatives.